# "Point" VS "Tip"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

Could someone please let me know if we can substitute "**you made very good [points](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/point)**" for "**you gave very good [tips](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/tip)**" in the following context:

> - You made very good points, but I would like to correct the fact that hurtful speech directed at one individual is not always protected free speech. [[Source]](https://medium.com/@adrian.dc/you-made-very-good-points-but-i-would-like-to-correct-the-fact-that-hurtful-speech-directed-at-one-4a6d66e005c6)

As dictionary says, both "point" and "tip" can mean a useful/helpful... piece of information. But I would like to know if they mean the same is a context like this.

Comment: A point is not the same as a tip. Have you looked up these words in a dictionary?

Comment: Points and tips are not (always) the same thing.  Tips are useful and helpful but points can be a detail.

Comment: A ***point*** in this context is an ***observation*** (a *statement* of some kind, which may or may not be intended to be helpful). But a ***tip*** is *always* intended to be "helpful advice". You could easily establish this difference by looking at any dictionary. The fact that there are *certain* contexts where the two words could be considered "interchangeable" doesn't somehow make this a valid question.

Comment: The links provided _are_ to dictionary definitions, Michael. However, note that the definition of _tip_ goes on to say _especially about how to do something or the likely winner of a race_. It does not mean the same as _point_ in this context.